# Is there any possibility to modify canonical commutation relations such that quantum field theory remains physically acceptable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

It is well known that standard commutation relations are given by
$$ [\phi(x), \phi(y)] = 0, [\pi(x), \pi(y)] = 0, [\phi(x), \pi(y)] = i\hbar\delta(x-y) $$
The problem associated with the last term is that when $x=y$, this commutation relation becomes $ [\phi(x), \pi(x)] = \infty $. This problem gives rise to other unsolved problems in quantum field theory like infinities occurring in the calculation of zero-point energy density and in the final answer of any process governed by the quantum field theory. The energy of quantum field is given by
$$ E = \int d^3p E_p \left( \hat{a}^\dagger_p \hat{a}_p + \frac{1}{2}\delta^3(0) \right) $$
Where in the second term of zero-point energy, the infinite term $\delta^3(0)$ is the indirect result of commutation relation $ [\phi(x), \pi(x)] = \infty $. Other nonsensical infinities occurring in the result of the theory have also their mathematical origin in the term $ [\phi(x), \pi(x)] = \infty $. Thus it looks like that given infinite input in terms of canonical commutation relation $ [\phi(x), \pi(x)] = \infty $, gives rise to the infinite output of the theory. Thus in order to overcome this problem, in my opinion, we should modify commutation relations such that they do not become infinite at any point. I know that some other tricks are there, like normal ordering and renormalization, to avoid such problems, but these tricks are not generally applicable. For example, the renormalization of the quantum field theory of gravity is not possible. Thus, if we can find an alternative form of canonical commutation relations that do not become infinite at any point and the form is also physically reasonable, we can find QFT without any infinity problems. Thus we will not need any such tricks that are not applicable in general, and we may be able to formulate a quantum field theory of gravity. Thus my question is that, is it physically acceptable to modify commutation relations? Moreover, if yes, what can be another physically acceptable form?

Comment: These commutation relations are direct consequences of the Poisson bracket between the canonical variables of your theory. Whatever independant canonical variables you use, the commutation relations will remain the same. One way to get rid of the Dirac delta is to work on a lattice, I think.

Comment: I've thought about the same question in the past, and my conclusions have been the same as those of @JeanbaptisteRoux. Or I've found the same obstacle. Namely: The delta on the RHS of canonical commutation or anticommutation rules is not a "crude picture" of a point-like particle to be smoothed out by a milder version, say some $\theta\left( x \right)$ --that'd be my physical motivation. The delta there is playing an essential role in the observable algebra. There would be no way to dispose of that without completely re-thinking the whole canonical formalism. Discreteness would be the option.

Comment: Like @JeanbaptisteRoux said, many QFTs of interest, including QED and QCD, can be constructed without any mathematical ambiguity by treating space(time) as a discrete lattice. Then the right-hand side of the commutation relation is an ordinary number, and everything is well-defined. Even though that approach is good enough for all practical purposes, it's also messy, and treating space(time) as a lattice is clearly artificial. Many QFTs (including QED) probably don't have any nontrivial continuum limit, but some (including QCD) surely do. Is the question restricted to continuous space(time)?

Comment: I have studied the derivation of commutation relation by Poisson bracket in quantum mechanics. However, in QFT, many standard texts have considered the particular form of commutation relation as a postulate of the theory. That is why I thought about the possibility of modifying commutation relation to solve problems of infinities in theory. @ Chiral Anomaly, currently, I am thinking about continuous spacetime only. Can anyone suggest any good reference from where I can get the idea of why the particular form of commutation relation is the only possible form in continuous spacetime?

Comment: One of the principles of QFT is microcausality (also called Einstein causality), which says that observables associated with spacelike-separated regions must commute with each other (to prevent faster-than-light signaling). So observables associated with different points in space at the same time must commute with each other. Given that postulate, the only way for any local observables to not commute with each other is to have something like $\delta(x-y)$ in the equal-time commutation relation. Are you only interested in alternatives that don't have this $\delta(x-y)$?

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly, actually I am interested in formulating the QFT in which problems of infinity doesn't occur naturally. So when I realised that introduction of Dirac delta function is causing various infinities in the theory, I started thinking about possible alternative of Dirac delta function in commutation relation. But if the replacement is causing other problems such that the theory becomes unphysical then I think replacement is just not possible!

Comment: I’ve had this exact thought and yeah, I don’t really see anyone talking about this.